# How to use the SQL server clock in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm writing an app which has a "check in" facility - essentially a system tray app that checks in every 20 seconds by writing to a SQL db.

I then have a second app that checks this table to see if the client has checked in, and performs an action if the client has not checked in for 60 seconds.

I need to ensure that the time written to the sql database is the local server time, not the client time - as otherwise I'll have synchronisation issues.

I'm using Linq-to-SQL - how can I acheive this?

Comment: Other option is to switch to QueryOver:
[sing-current-timestamp-in-nhibernate-queryover-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155454/using-current-timestamp-in-nhibernate-queryover-syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually as a general rule of thumb you should not use the local time of the server either - use UTC time ([Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) instead.

In Linq to Sql you can use [`SqlFunctions.GetUtcDate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.getutcdate.aspx) for this which maps to [`GETUTCDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) in SQL Server.

Comment: `SqlFunctions.GetUtcDate()` is Link to entities not Link to SQL

Answer (score 4):

Write a user defined function that returns `GetDate()` and add it to you dbml file

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[Function(Name="GetDate", IsComposable=true)] 
 public DateTime GetSystemDate() 
 {   
    MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;   
    return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[]{}).ReturnValue; 
 }
```

EDIT: this needs to be a part of your DataContext class.

Answer (score 1):

This solution for any .NET version: it should be more beneficial for the speed and network traffic than other solutions.

1) create the function in SQL server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSQLServerDate] 
()
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result datetime
    SELECT @Result = getdate()
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

2) Add function to your LINQ to SQL diagram into the Stored Procedures section

3) Call your function from your code

```
THEDBDataContext DBConn = new THEDBDataContext ();
DateTime dt = (DateTime) DBConn.GetSQLServerDate();
```

Comment: **PLEASE DONT SHOUT** - seriously: all upper-case text is hard to read, bolding large amounts of text hides what's really important

Answer (score 1):

Acaz Souza's answer works, but it needs to be part of the data context. To put it outside the specific data context class, which is probably more reusable, try this as an extension method:

```
public static DateTime GetSystemDate(this DataContext db)
{
    return db.ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()").Single();
}
```

Comment: This helped me figure out the date and time on my remote server using LinqPad.  Anyway here's how to do it with the UTC date and time instead: ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETUTCDATE()").Single().Dump();